# Turning React Native project into Android Instant Apps

Tags: react-native, android-instant-apps

I am currently trying to do it using clean react native project. I followed official android instant apps guides.

What I did to turn react-native into Android Instant Apps

1. Renamed `app` module to `base` module
2. Removed `splits` and `applicationVariants` in `build.gradle`
3. Created `installed` module and `instantApp` module.
4. Added `import OutputFile`, `entryFile`, and `apply from react.gradle` inside `installed` module

However, I am running into following problems.

1. `react-native run-android` fails because it is still looking for app module.
2. Running `instantApp` from Android Studio will run the app on my phone, but failing to download JS from my React metro bundler even after running it manually and executing `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`
3. Renaming base module back to app module and running react-native run-android still fails with error message Error: Activity class {com.instantapp/com.instantapp.MainActivity} does not exist.

I tried searching everywhere but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: were you able to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

After renaming the app module to 'base' you will need to create another app module in your project (google's guides suggest to name it 'installed', but I would use 'app' instead in order to avoid this problem with react-native). Make react-native look for your new app module.
This should resolve your problem, but I really don't think you will be able to build a 4MB-or-less apk file using React Native, remember that this is the maximum size an Instant App apk can have.

Comment: Note, for the full experience, 4mb is required (for non-games), otherwise 10mb is ok for a Try Now experience, see https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/overview#reduce-size

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Also, according to this report it appears to be possible to build a RN apk with 3.5mb - https://medium.com/@aswinmohanme/how-i-reduced-the-size-of-my-react-native-app-by-86-27be72bba640

Comment: @HenriqueCamposdeFreitas thank you for the answer. I followed the steps to rename to 'base' and creating another module named 'installed'. I also added 'instantapp' module as well.

Can you be more specific what you mean by "Make react-native look for your new app module." ? I tried to dig into the react-native source code but still can't figure out why my app can't connect to my metro bundler (even after adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081)

Comment: @EricKim Have you found any way to do this ? (yes i'm digging a 3-years-old post :))

Comment: @JohnSmith No unfortunately not, I am looking into just using web apps with fullscreen mode